# Flask request form username does not equal database text when it should

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

When checking if the textbox username equals the username from the database, it doesn't equal when it should. I tested this on a separate debug page where it would print out the text from the database, and it printed out the right text. I printed out the username in the error text to test it, and it printed out the same username, but Python says the form username does not equal the database username.

Login Page Code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    db = get_db().cursor()
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != db.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?', (request.form['username'],)).fetchone():
            error = 'Invalid username. Username text was: ' + request.form['username']
        elif request.form['password'] != db.execute('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?', (request.form['username'], request.form['password'],)).fetchone():
            error = 'Invalid password'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Database Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT unique,
        email TEXT unique, password TEXT, rank INT)
```

Example: I type in `spideynn` and the username in the database is `spideynn` but it doesn't equal.

I am new to SQLite3, and new to Python websites, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not fetching the column value from the result. Try rewriting it as:

```
if request.form['username'] != db.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?', (request.form['username'],)).fetchone()['username']:
```

Comment: This is one of the things that they never mention in the tutorials. Thanks!